# Sandbox environment for "php malware" analysis

Tags: malware, php, sandbox, static-analysis

I would like to know how can I analyse an obfuscated malware php code ?
I heard about cuckoo sandbox, but it seems too overwhelming for this particular task.
So I decided to run a Vagrant box, install php-cli, tcpdump, ... run the php code and look for connections with tcpdump for example ...

What would you do in such case ?
I would like to know if there is some dedicated tools for specific php malware/backdoor analysis ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all of the PHP code for the application you can set up a LAMP/WAMP VM and load it up on an [IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/php-ide/). You can run it and set your breakpoints as needed.

Turn off the network card and install and run [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) in the background. If you need to you can look into some [DNS spoofing](http://blog.zeltser.com/post/11869187517/fake-dns-tools-for-malware-analysis) applications.

If you're very concerned do all of this on dedicated hardware that is not connected to any network.

That should be enough to get you started.